# ¿Cómo cambiar el layout de un módulo en Joomla?

Tags: joomla3

Estoy usando el template Beez que viene con Joomla! 3.6, y estoy incluyendo un módulo personalizado (mod_custom) en una posición de dicho template.

Al momento de ir a mirar el código del template para modificar el layout que utiliza, todo lo que encuentro es:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="beezDivision" headerlevel="3" />
```

`position-9` es la posición donde estoy ubicando el módulo, pero quiero modificar el código que se agrega a la información que yo ingreso, lo explico a continuación:

```
<div class="moduletablemimodulo">
    <h3>prueba</h3>
    <div class="custommimodulo"  >
    Lemon drops gummies biscuit. Cotton candy pie toffee bear claw pudding marzipan chocolate cake fruitcake.
    </div>
</div>
```

De el código anterior, yo agrego por medio del administrador de Joomla! el título *prueba*, una clase *mimodulo* y el texto que está después del `<h3>`.

Lo que yo quiero es que en vez de ese código, aparezca algo así:

```
<div class="mimodulo">
    <h4>prueba</h4>
    <span class="contenido">
    Lemon drops gummies biscuit. Cotton candy pie toffee bear claw pudding marzipan chocolate cake fruitcake.
    </span>
</div>
```

No he encontrado por donde puedo modificarlo en el backend de Joomla!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder cambiar las etiquetas del módulo debes hacer modificaciones en dos partes (en cuanto a código), las cuales deberían realizarse normalmente en una nueva plantilla, para evitar sobreescribir Beez con las actualizaciones de Joomla!:

1. Modificar el chrome del módulo:

   Según la [documentación de Joomla!](https://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome/es)

   > El módulo chrome permite a los diseñadores de plantillas tener un cierto control sobre la manera en que la salida de un Módulo se muestra en la plantilla. Esencialmente, consta de una pequeña cantidad de HTML predefinido que se inserta antes de, o después de, o alrededor de la salida de cada módulo, y que luego se le puede dar un estilo con CSS.
   >
   > El módulo chrome es determinado por el uso de 'style', el atributo en la declaración que llama al módulo.

   En este caso el chrome de tu módulo es **beezDivision**, y su código respectivo lo encuentras en templates/beez3/html/modules.php:

   ```
   function modChrome_beezDivision($module, &$params, &$attribs)
   {
       $headerLevel = isset($attribs['headerLevel']) ? (int) $attribs['headerLevel'] : 3;
       if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
           <div class="moduletable<?php echo htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
           <?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
               <h<?php echo $headerLevel; ?>><?php echo $module->title; ?></h<?php echo $headerLevel; ?>>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php echo $module->content; ?></div>
       <?php endif;
   }
   ```

   Aquí puedes crear otra función en el mismo archivo o modificar beezDivision (no recomendado):

   ```
   function modChrome_miEstilo($module, &$params, &$attribs)
   {
       $headerLevel = isset($attribs['headerLevel']) ? (int) $attribs['headerLevel'] : 4;
       if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
           <?php // ---- aquí quitamos la clase moduletable ---- ?>
           <div class="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
           <?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
               <h<?php echo $headerLevel; ?>><?php echo $module->title; ?></h<?php echo $headerLevel; ?>>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php echo $module->content; ?></div>
       <?php endif;
   }
   ```

   Los dos únicos cambios que realicé aquí fueron quitar el prefijo de clase `moduletable` y cambiar el nivel de encabezado por defecto a h4, aunque este lo puedes seleccionar en la configuración avanzada de tu módulo en el backend.

---

2. Hacer un override del template del módulo mod_custom:

   Esto lo puedes hacer en el backend de Joomla!, editando los estilos de tu plantilla, en la pestaña "Modificaciones", seleccionando "mod_custom".

   El código que vas a encontrar en templates/beez3/html/mod_custom/default.php es el siguiente:

   ```
   <div class="custom<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>" <?php if ($params->get('backgroundimage')) : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $params->get('backgroundimage');?>)"<?php endif;?> >
       <?php echo $module->content;?>
   </div>
   ```

   Para obtener lo que quieres, deberías modificarlo a algo como esto:

   ```
   <span class="contenido" <?php if ($params->get('backgroundimage')) : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $params->get('backgroundimage');?>)"<?php endif;?> >
       <?php echo $module->content;?>
   </span>
   ```

   Puedes ver un poco más de información en la [documentación de Joomla!](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core/es).